Inductive effect in Boron
BH2 shows -I effect but i cant figure out why from the varied reasonings I've been told.
First reason: This happens due to the presence of a vacant orbital on boron, where B is pulling electron density to complete its octet... But I cant see why that would affect its inductive effect...Won't the presence of a vacant orbital just affect the mesomeric effect caused by B.
Second reason: This is because H is more electronegative than B, so it would pull electron density towards itself... But here wouldn't neighboring C atoms do the same? And being more electronegative than H, the C would attract electron density towards themselves and thus a +I effect would be caused...

This question is similar to: Can alkyl groups show -I effect?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
